# How to sort a list in python based on another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a python list with user ids
`data = [123,456,789]` 
and I want to sort this list based on how many points they have (calculated by points[userid]). I have tried `SortedData = sorted(data,key=points,reverse=True)` to no avail. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.
Evan

Comment: Assuming that `points` is a `dict`, you can use `points.get` as a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to epxlicit it in a `lambda`.  You could di `points[x]` but `points.get(x,0)` may be safer here

```
data = [123,456,789]
points = {123:20, 456:10, 789:15}
sortedData = sorted(data, key=lambda x:points.get(x,0), reverse=True)
print(sortedData)
```

---

If you're ok of letting `None` as default value instead of a number, you can reduce to

```
sortedData = sorted(data, key=points.get, reverse=True) # use the method itself
```

Answer (score 0):

`key` also accepts a function.

Try this:

```py
sorted_list = list(sorted(data, key= lambda userid: points[userid], reverse=True))
```